# Proving two points on a line exists which is equidistant from two intersecting lines

Tags: geometry

If two straight lines AB and CD meet at O , and there is another line XY . prove in general that there are two points on XY that are equidistant from the two lines

Comment: Are you sure this is true in general?  Maybe I misunderstand the problem, but if the lines $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ are $y = x$ and $y = -x$, and line $\overline{XY}$ is, say, $x = 5$, then the only point on $\overline{XY}$ that is equidistant from both $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ is $(5, 0)$.

Comment: If $\overline{XY}$ is not parallel to the bisector of any of the angles formed by $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$, then it seems there would be two points on $\overline{XY}$ that qualify.

Comment: @BrianTung But that is a special case - there are two angle bisectors here and any line which is not parallel to one of these will intersect both. The only other special case will be lines passing through O

Comment: @MarkBennet: I agree it is a special case, but I take "in general" to mean "in all cases," rather than "in all but a few special cases."  Maybe the OP can clarify.

Comment: As far is I know even I was confused but I have written the exact question from a book

Answer (score 1):

We know that any point lying on angle bisector of two lines is equidistant from both the lines.

Now we know that the third line would definitely intersect both the angle bisectors until it is parallel to one of the bisector.

If it is parallel to one of the bisectors, then there would be only 1 which would be equidistant from  both the lines.